# How to set and resolve openshift_master_cluster_hostname?

Tags: ansible, openshift

I'm trying to install OKD 3.11 with mutiple masters but never succeeded. I'm using three master nodes, two work nodes and one lb node. The failure is related to setting and resolving 'openshift_master_cluster_hostname' and 'openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname'. Here is my inventory file, DNS setting and /etc/hosts file. Could you please let me know what's wrong ?

DNS server is running on ubuntu 16.04.
/etc/bind/db.zanity.net

```
;
; BIND data file for zone "zanity.net"
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.
@       IN      A       127.0.0.1
osc-console          IN A 192.168.219.51
osc-console.internal IN A 192.168.219.51
osc-lb               IN A 192.168.219.50
osc-master01         IN A 192.168.219.51
osc-master02         IN A 192.168.219.52
osc-master03         IN A 192.168.219.53
osc-node01           IN A 192.168.219.54
```

/etc/hosts files of the master and worker nodes.

```
[root@osc-master01 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.219.100 linux-server

192.168.219.50 osc-lb
192.168.219.51 osc-console
192.168.219.51 osc-console.internal

192.168.219.51 osc-master01
192.168.219.52 osc-master02
192.168.219.53 osc-master03
192.168.219.54 osc-node01
192.168.219.55 osc-node02
```

Inventory files in master01 (installation node)
/etc/ansible/hosts

```
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
nfs
etcd
lb

[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
openshift_deployment_type=origin

openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]
openshift_master_htpasswd_users={'admin': '$apr1$RbOvaj8r$LEqJqG6V/O/i7Pf...'}

openshift_master_cluster_method=native
openshift_master_cluster_hostname=osc-console.internal.zanity.net
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=osc-console.zanity.net

openshift_node_groups=[{'name': 'node-config-master', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true']}, {'name': 'node-config-infra', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/infra=true']}, {'name': 'node-config-compute', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/compute=true']}, {'name': 'node-config-compute-storage', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/compute-storage=true']}]

openshift_disable_check=memory_availability,docker_image_availability

[masters]
osc-master01.zanity.net
osc-master02.zanity.net
osc-master03.zanity.net

[nodes]
osc-master01.zanity.net openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master'
osc-master02.zanity.net openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master'
osc-master03.zanity.net openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master'
osc-node01.zanity.net openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
osc-node02.zanity.net openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
osc-node02.zanity.net openshift_node_group_name='node-config-infra'

[etcd]
osc-master01.zanity.net
osc-master02.zanity.net
osc-master03.zanity.net

[nfs]
osc-master02.zanity.net

[lb]
osc-lb.zanity.net
[root@osc-master01 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.219.100 linux-server

192.168.219.50 osc-lb
192.168.219.51 osc-console
192.168.219.51 osc-console.internal

192.168.219.51 osc-master01
192.168.219.52 osc-master02
192.168.219.53 osc-master03
192.168.219.54 osc-node01
192.168.219.55 osc-node02
```

I tried following combinations to resolve addresses of hostname and public hostname and all them failed.
Case 1) 
192.168.219.50 osc-lb
192.168.219.50 osc-console
192.168.219.50 osc-console.internal
=> Failed with "Control plane pods didn't come up"

Case 2)
92.168.219.50 osc-lb
192.168.219.50 osc-console
192.168.219.51 osc-console.internal
=> Failed with "Control plane pods didn't come up"
or
=> Failed with something related to customer certification.

Case 3)
92.168.219.50 osc-lb
192.168.219.51 osc-console
192.168.219.51 osc-console.internal
=> Failed with followings

```
PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=13   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
osc-lb.zanity.net          : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=26   rescued=0    ignored=0
osc-master01.zanity.net    : ok=303  changed=120  unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=237  rescued=0    ignored=0
osc-master02.zanity.net    : ok=254  changed=104  unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=217  rescued=0    ignored=0
osc-master03.zanity.net    : ok=243  changed=103  unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=213  rescued=0    ignored=0
osc-node01.zanity.net      : ok=100  changed=34   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=96   rescued=0    ignored=0
osc-node02.zanity.net      : ok=100  changed=34   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=96   rescued=0    ignored=0


INSTALLER STATUS ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Initialization              : Complete (0:00:23)
Health Check                : Complete (0:00:12)
Node Bootstrap Preparation  : Complete (0:05:43)
etcd Install                : Complete (0:00:42)
NFS Install                 : Complete (0:00:04)
Load Balancer Install       : Complete (0:00:00)
Master Install              : In Progress (0:22:19)
        This phase can be restarted by running: playbooks/openshift-master/config.yml
Tuesday 08 October 2019  16:07:08 +0900 (0:18:46.369)       0:29:22.463 *******
===============================================================================
openshift_control_plane : Wait for all control plane pods to become ready ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1126.37s
openshift_node : Install node, clients, and conntrack packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 224.22s
openshift_control_plane : Wait for control plane pods to appear ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 94.48s
openshift_ca : Install the base package for admin tooling ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 12.48s
Run health checks (install) - EL -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 11.84s
openshift_excluder : Install openshift excluder - yum ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 10.33s
openshift_excluder : Install docker excluder - yum --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 8.80s
openshift_cli : Install clients ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 5.68s
openshift_master_certificates : copy ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 5.63s
openshift_node : Update journald setup --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 4.53s
tuned : Ensure files are populated from templates ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.94s
openshift_master_certificates : Check status of master certificates ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.53s
openshift_node : Add iptables allow rules ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 3.17s
openshift_control_plane : Copy static master scripts ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.12s
Gathering Facts -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.12s
openshift_control_plane : Prepare master static pods ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3.07s
tuned : Restart tuned service ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 2.33s
openshift_node : install needed rpm(s) --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.13s
openshift_node : create directories for bootstrapping --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.11s
openshift_control_plane : Ensure htpasswd file exists ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 2.07s


Failure summary:


  1. Hosts:    osc-lb.zanity.net
     Play:     Initialize cluster facts
     Task:     Gather Cluster facts
     Message:  MODULE FAILURE
               See stdout/stderr for the exact error

  2. Hosts:    osc-master03.zanity.net
     Play:     Configure masters
     Task:     Wait for all control plane pods to become ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the `osc-console.internal.zanity.net` at the same level as the other hosts to avoid any DNS resolution issues. 
For example, rename it `osc-console-internal.zanity.net`.

Also, as per documentation, `openshift_master_cluster_hostname` and `openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname` must be backed by a balancing service. 
If you are using the balancer deployed during installation, check that

- the load balancing service is properly configured by the ansible playbook and it is configured to balance between master nodes on port `:8443`.
- your dns record for `openshift_master_cluster_hostname` points to the lb service.

```
[...]
# Native high availability cluster method with optional load balancer.
# If no lb group is defined installer assumes that a load balancer has
# been preconfigured. For installation the value of
# openshift_master_cluster_hostname must resolve to the load balancer
# or to one or all of the masters defined in the inventory if no load
# balancer is present.
[...]
```

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/example_inventories.html#multi-masters-single-etcd-using-native-ha

Answer (score 0):

@IMA,
Thanks for your answer.
I changed the FQDN for the internal access to osc-console-internal.zanity.net as you suggested but it didnt' work.
Currently I have 'Console install failed' error.

In this trial, I used same /etc/hosts files for all masters and nodes with below values.

```
[root@osc-master01 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.219.100 linux-server

192.168.219.50 osc-lb osc-lb.zanity.net
192.168.219.50 osc-console osc-console.zanity.net
192.168.219.50 osc-console-internal osc-console-internal.zanity.net

192.168.219.51 osc-master01 osc-master01.zanity.net
192.168.219.52 osc-master02 osc-master02.zanity.net
192.168.219.53 osc-master03 osc-master03.zanity.net
192.168.219.54 osc-node01 osc-node01.zanity.net
192.168.219.55 osc-node02 osc-node02.zanity.net
```

And I set up external DNS sever on a different host other than masters and nodes with below seeting.

```
;
; BIND data file for zone "zanity.net"
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.
@       IN      A       127.0.0.1
osc-console          IN A 192.168.219.50
osc-console-internal IN A 192.168.219.50
osc-lb               IN A 192.168.219.50
osc-master01         IN A 192.168.219.51
osc-master02         IN A 192.168.219.52
osc-master03         IN A 192.168.219.53
osc-node01           IN A 192.168.219.54
osc-node02           IN A 192.168.219.55
```

From the journalctl -xe, I see error line like below.

`10월 15 12:57:44 osc-master01.zanity.net dockerd-current[5411]: Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.219.50:8443: connect: no route to host.`

Here is result of 'netstat -anlp | grep 8443'.

```
[root@osc-master01 ~]# netstat -anlp | grep 8443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18385/openshift
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:8443     192.168.219.51:40256    ESTABLISHED 18385/openshift
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:56798    192.168.219.51:8443     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:40320    192.168.219.51:8443     ESTABLISHED 18403/openshift
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:54854    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:8443     192.168.219.51:40320    ESTABLISHED 18385/openshift
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:54840    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:55054    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:55060    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:40256    192.168.219.51:8443     ESTABLISHED 18385/openshift
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:39842    192.168.219.51:8443     ESTABLISHED 18403/openshift
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:55052    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:55056    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:8443     192.168.219.52:37364    ESTABLISHED 18385/openshift
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:54894    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:54944    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:56704    192.168.219.51:8443     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.219.51:8443     192.168.219.51:39842    ESTABLISHED 18385/openshift
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:54846    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      1 192.168.219.51:55058    192.168.219.50:8443     SYN_SENT    26590/hyperkube
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8443          127.0.0.1:42976         ESTABLISHED 18385/openshift
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42976         127.0.0.1:8443          ESTABLISHED 18385/openshift
```

There may be something wrong in resolving ip addresses for osc-console.zanity.net.
Could you let me know what it is ?